G*Power sample size calculation between regression coefficients in two separate within-subject models
I have two identical regression models run on two different subsamples. In R, my models would be the following:
library(fixest)
library(tidyverse)

mod1 <- feols(outcome ~ treatment | id, data=df %>% filter(group == 1)) 
mod2 <- feols(outcome ~ treatment | id, data=df) %>% filter(group == 2))  

where treatment is a factor variable with levels control, 1, and 2 (control is the reference and is dropped). id is the respondent ID, so the above represents a respondent fixed effect enabling the within-subject design.
For my analysis, I want to compare the difference between the significance of the effect for treatment1 in mod1 vs treatment1 in mod2.
I need to perform an a priori power calculation for the number of respondents required to have a test at 0.8 power at 95% confidence. I am trying to use G*Power to calculate this, but I am unsure what is the proper setting to use. My intuition is that t-tests would be appropriate for this setting given I am comparing regression coefficients, but when they are from two different models, what would be the appropriate settings? If it asks for standard deviations, would I use the standard deviation specific to the particular subset? Am I going about this wrong and there is a different test to use? If so, can you please provide an example of a proper power calculation based on the estimate of interest as the difference between two regression coefficients in two within-respondent models.
